# diacritics deploying Java EE app

Tags: linux, jakarta-ee, glassfish, diacritics

I have an app that is sending mail via GlassFish JavaMail Session.

I have localhost and production server, when I deploy the app on localhost - development - everything is ok, but on production, the letters in the e-mail with diacritics are not displayed properly, but as ??? question marks. The acute letters works:`áéóíú`, but the caron `ščřďťňž` don't. Do you know where I should start to find the solution? Both are linux machines - one is Arch the other Debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the encoding on one machine is utf-8 and the other is e.g. iso-8859-1?

Comment: check the encoding of the machine, the jvm config at startup, the encoding of the file you are building with the javamail api...